# How to connect MacBook to the Pulseaudio via bluetooth?

Tags: linux, mac, audio, bluetooth, pulse-audio

I'm running Fedora on a home server with wired speakers connected. I have set up the Pulseaudio as A2DP Bluetooth device. I can connect my Android phones to it and play music. But my MacBook fails to do the same.

The Mac is successfully paired with my PC. Also, I set to use PC as audio device on Mac. After I start playing music - the Mac connects to PC via bluetooth automatically, hangs for some time and then says, that it failed to use bluetooth device to play audio - and disconnects. No actual sound is produced.

Is it a known problem?

P.S. I have filed a [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72862%20bug) to pulseaudio - in case, it's their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works, starting with `bluez-5.14`